# MySQL: GROUP_CONCAT() slow query (3+ seconds) - how to optimise?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have the following query which selects **players** in order of their **leaderboard** position and alongside that gives their latest **post** and a number of latest **stories** involving that player, which are group_concatted so I have one row per player, with multiple stories in each row.

```
SELECT  players.player_name, 
        posts. * , 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT stories.story_title 
                      ORDER BY stories.story_published DESC 
                      SEPARATOR  '[sep]' ) 
                      AS headlines, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT stories.story_link 
                      ORDER BY stories.story_published DESC 
                      SEPARATOR  '[sep]' )
                      AS links
FROM    players, player_stories, stories, posts, leaderboard
WHERE   cs_player_id = player_id
  AND   cs_story_id = story_id
  AND   post_player = player_id
  AND   leaderboard.name = players.player_name
GROUP BY players.player_name
ORDER BY leaderboard.1 DESC , leaderboard.3 DESC , leaderboard.6 DESC , leaderboard.144     DESC
```

I have primary keys on all _id fields and I have indexes on all other fields which are used in the joins.

But it's loading slowly - approx 3 seconds per query.

All fields are fixed length (VARCHAR or INT)

Is there a way to optimise this query?

EDIT: Here it is on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b55cf/1/0

Worth noting in my actual implementation each table has between 1000 and 3000 rows.

EXPLAIN EXTENDED gives:

```
id  select_type  table          type      possible_keys         key        key_len  ref                                       rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE       player_stories index     PRIMARY               PRIMARY    8        NULL                                      1169  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       players        eq_ref    PRIMARY               PRIMARY    4        player_stories.cs_player_id               1 
1   SIMPLE       leaderboard    ref       Bothnames,name        name       152      func                                      1     Using where
1   SIMPLE       posts          ref       uniqueLink,post_playeruniqueLink 4        players.player_id                         24    Using where
1   SIMPLE       stories        eq_ref    PRIMARY               PRIMARY    4        player_stories.cs_story_id                1 



Variable_name                   Value
bulk_insert_buffer_size         8388608
innodb_buffer_pool_awe_mem_mb       0
innodb_buffer_pool_size         8388608
innodb_log_buffer_size          1048576
join_buffer_size                    131072
key_buffer_size                 8384512
myisam_sort_buffer_size         8388608
net_buffer_length                   16384
preload_buffer_size                 32768
read_buffer_size                    131072
read_rnd_buffer_size            262144
sort_buffer_size                    2097144
```

Comment: Get rid of posts. *  from SELECT

Comment: Could you add EXPLAIN output?

Comment: How about posting the CREATE TABLE for each table (so we can see the indexes).  You may also want to set a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I have added an SQL Fiddle. It was a fiddle.

Comment: Could you please add the results of: `show variables like '%buffer%'`

Comment: Is it possible to increase `[key|join]_buffer_size`? As for now you have the default values.

Comment: Sadly I can't change these values - I'm on a shared environment!